# Resize handler works once, but not twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, resize

I'm writing code that handles the resize event, and ran into some trouble.
Here is the code:

```
/* 
   Timeline.js

   (Requires jquery, developed with jquery-1.4.4.min.js in mind)   
*/

/*
  Timeline's two major functions are setup and draw. After instantiating a 
  timeline object, the developer calls setup() to initialize the object. Later,
  the developer repeatedly calls on draw() to animate the canvas.
  In between, resizing the window may trigger the resize() function which 
  adjusts the timeline's dimensions and other settings.
*/
function Timeline(){
    // constants
    Timeline._BORDER_SIDES = 20; // The border on each side of the timeline,
    // We'll need this value later when calculating back's top offset
    Timeline._OFFSET_LEFT = '8px'; 
    Timeline._OFFSET_TOP = '8px'; // top border, 8px seems to be chrome default
    Timeline._BUTTON_WIDTH = 17; // The length of the back and forward buttons
    Timeline._WIDTH_FACTOR = 2/3; // How much height timeline should take up
    // variables
    Timeline._id = 0; // An id wich is unique for each instance of Timeline

    /* This function is called when the user clicks the back div*/
    this._backHandler = function(){
    alert('back clicked');
    };

    this._testResize = function(){
    alert('resized');
    };


    /*
      timeline.setup()
      Create canvas, back and forward button, as well as slider for scale.
      timeline_wrapper_id is the id of an element which is to contain this
      specific timeline.
     */    
    this.setup = function(timeline_wrapper_id){
    // add canvas
    this._id = Timeline._id++; // get id, create next id for next instance
    this._timeline_wrapper_id = timeline_wrapper_id;
    this._canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this._canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas' + this._id);
    $('#' + timeline_wrapper_id).append(this._canvas);

    // add back button
    this._back = document.createElement('div');
    this._back.setAttribute('id', 'back' + this._id); 
    // id's help us jquery stuff, ensuring their unique across instances
    // lets us potentially put several instance on the same page.

    this._back.onclick = this._backHandler; // set event handler: onclick
    $('#' + timeline_wrapper_id).append(this._back);


    this._resizeHandler = function(){
        // First, we clear all style so as to prevent duplicates
        $('#canvas' + this._id).removeAttr('style');
        $('#back' + this._id).removeAttr('style');
        // later we'll insert an empty style before modifying the style.


        // set canvas attributes

        // Width of canvas is window width, with space for borders either 
        // side.
        var canvas_width = $(window).width() - Timeline._BORDER_SIDES*2;
        var canvas_height = $(window).height() * Timeline._HEIGHT_FACTOR;


        /* The core feature of this block is the z-index. Everything else 
           is there because otherwise I can't determine the z-index. At 
           least that's what I read somewhere.

           The z-index determines how overlapping elements are drawn.
           The higher the z-index, the "closer to the user" the element is.

           In this case, we want to draw everything on top of the canvas,
           hence the lowest z-index in our application: 0.
        */
        $('#canvas'+this._id).attr('style', ''); 
        // this undoes our removeAttr('style') from earlier

        $('#canvas' + this._id).css({
        width: canvas_width,
        height: canvas_height,
        border: '1px solid', // to see what's going on
        position: 'relative', // "take canvas out of flow"-rough quote
        top: Timeline._BORDER_TOP, // seems to be the chrome default
        left: Timeline._BORDER_LEFT, // ditto
        'z-index': 0
        });

        /* Here we define the back button's visual properties. 
           Where possible, we calculate them in terms of canvas attributes,
           to achieve a consistent layout as the browser is resized.
        */
        var back_left = $('#canvas' + this._id).css('left') + 'px'; 
        // same distance from left timeline_wrapper as canvas

        // This one is a little more difficult: An explanation will follow
        // as soon as I've figured it out myself.
        var back_top = ((-1)*$('#canvas' + this._id).height() - 6) + 'px';

        $('#back' + this._id).attr('style', ''); 
        $('#back' + this._id).css({
        'background-color': '#336699',
        width: Timeline._BUTTON_WIDTH,
        height: $('#canvas' + this._id).height(), // fill canvas height
        position: 'relative', // same reason as for canvas
        left: back_left,
        top: back_top,
        'z-index': 1
        });
    };


    this._resizeHandler();
    $(window).resize(this._resizeHandler);
    };

    /*
      timeline.draw()
      Update (or set for the first time) the styles of back and forward button,
      as well as the canvas.
      Assumes setup has been called.
     */
    this.draw = function(){
    console.log('dummy');
    };
}
```

The code calling Timeline.js is pretty simple:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>timeline-js</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Timeline.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timeline_wrapper"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.setup('timeline_wrapper');
// timeline.draw();
//setInterval('timeline.draw()', 60);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The resize function doesn't throw any errors in Chrome, and works when called like so:

```
this._resizeHandler();
```

The error handler is called, I know that because setting `window.onresize = this._testReszie` works fine, too.

However, when I combine the two, the canvas doesn't resize with the window.
Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: The code can also be found at http://code.google.com/p/timeline-js/source/browse/Timeline.js, with slightly better formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in your `_resizeHandler` function, `this` does not refer to your Timeline instance. Instead it refers to `window` since that's what the handler has been attached to.

On way of fixing it (and this is not the only way) is to redefine `_resizeHandler` so that it gets a reference to the Timeline instance.

```
this._resizeHandler = function(self){
  ...same code but with 'this' replaced by 'self'...
}
```

And then fix up the call sites:

```
this._resizeHandler(this);
var thisTimeline = this;
$(window).resize(function() { thisTimeline._resizeHandler(thisTimeline); });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked beautifully! Will this happen for each event handler? (Pun fully acknowledged, but not intended)

Comment: Indeed. You've just got to remember that when an event handler is called the this object is going to be the object the event handler was attached to. So, you have to go through some of this kind of workaround to make sure you have an explicit reference to whatever it is you're interested in inside the handler.